# Why dask's "to_sql" is taking more time than pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dask

I am using `dask` instead of `pandas` for ETL i.e. to read a CSV from S3 bucket, then making some transformations required. Until here - dask is faster than pandas to read and apply the transformations!

In the end I'm dumping the transformed data to Redshift using to_sql. This to_sql dump in dask is taking more time than in pandas.

Is it possible to reduce this time taken? If not, why is dask slower than pandas in this case?

Comment: Are you certain it's not using "lazy execution" - this is, it does all the processing only when the dump is called. Are you using the `parallel` parameter?

Comment: nope, maybe i should try again with `compute=True` and `parallel=True` ?

Comment: @JithendraYenugula there's a lot to add to your question: how big is processed data? What is the difference between pandas and dask `to_sql` in seconds? ideally, you need to post both pandas and dask `to_sql` expressions with all the parameters.

Comment: I experimented dask for two situations.  1) Dumping 1lakh rows dataframe into RedShift took 5mins and now, 2) dumping 20lakh rows dataframe is taking 20*5 minutes! which is greater than 1.5 hours!  I'm using this - `dask.DataFrame.to_sql(chunksize=10000,compute=True,parallel=True, method='multi')` . Any way to optimize this? because greater than 1 hour to RedShift will make me to use EC2 instead of Lambda in ETL pipeline!

Answer (score 1):

Dask DataFrames consist of different partitions, each of which is a Pandas DataFrame.  Dask I/O is fast when operations can be run on each partition in parallel.  When you can write out a Dask DataFrame as 10 files, that'll be faster than writing one file for example.

It a similar concept when writing to a database.  If you can write all the partitions to the database in parallel, that'll be a lot faster than writing them all sequentially.

`to_sql` sets `parallel=False` by default.  Let's look at the description for that argument:

> When true, have each block append itself to the DB table concurrently. This can result in DB rows being in a different order than the source DataFrame’s corresponding rows. When false, load each block into the SQL DB in sequence.

One of your comments says "greater than 1 hour to RedShift will make me to use EC2 instead of Lambda in ETL pipeline" which indicates you may be using Dask in a Lambda function?  If you're running this code in Lambda, not a proper ec2 instance / cluster, then writing to Redshift with [aws-data-wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) may be a better option.